# add a Navigation controller to a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've just worked through a tutorial on how to create a Navigation controller starting with a Window-Based application project.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to applied the methods I used in the tutorial with a root view that has a tab bar controller.

I've set up a tab bar controller, again using the window-based app project, and added four tab bar items that are linked to their respective UIViewController classes/nib.

Can I add a nav controller like I did with my window-based tutorial to the UIViewController classes?

Here is how i created a nav controller by itself:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NavAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@end




#import "NavAppDelegate.h"

@implementation NavAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}



etc...
```

Comment: Go to your Interface Builder and look at the tab bar controller. There you have got your four tabs and for each tab you probably have a view controller. Instead of having a view controller, try dragging a navigation controller on top of your tab bar and remove your previous view controllers. Now you should have navigation controller with a view controller inside of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` are **controllers of controllers**, i.e. they manage multiple `UIViewControllers`. The `UIViewControllers` in turn manage the views. So the title of your question does need revision.

The standard setup is this: `UITabBarController` is the root controller. Each tab controls **either** a `UIViewController` **or** a `UINavigationController` which in turn manages `UIViewControllers`.

So you add `UIViewControllers` or `UINavigationControllers` to your tab bar items.

Thus, the direct answer to your question is: *no*. You **cannot** add a `UINavigationController` to your `UIViewController`but rather the other way round.

Comment: ok, so I just changed my UIViewController class with UINavigationController. Thanks!

Comment: but wait... do I need to set up an outlet from my class to my nav controller in my nib?

Comment: You can add a nav controller object directly in IB and link it to the appropriate view controllers. Not exactly an `IBOutlet`.