# UITableView- tap into the cell and get the next view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have problems entering a next view in the TableViewController.
When I click on the cells i see the NSLog-text, but there is no action and no second view.
This means the program enter the methods but does nothing. What is my fault?
I am testing around without getting any solution.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        NSLog(@"Index 0");
        AudioViewController *audioviewcontroller = [[AudioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AudioViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navController pushViewController:audioviewcontroller animated:YES];
        [audioviewcontroller release];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];

    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        NSLog(@"Index 1");
        DisplayViewController *displayviewcontroller = [[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navController pushViewController:displayviewcontroller animated:YES];
        [displayviewcontroller release];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2) {
        LichtViewController *lichtviewcontroller = [[LichtViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LichtViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navController pushViewController:lichtViewController animated:YES];
        [lichtviewcontroller release];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Index 2");
    }
    if (indexPath.row==3) {
        NSLog(@"Index 3");
        ProjektorViewController *projektorviewcontroller = [[ProjektorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjektorViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navController pushViewController:projektorviewcontroller animated:YES];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
        [projektorviewcontroller release];

    }
}
```

Moreover I tried this code:

```
UIView *currentView = self.view;    
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
[currentView removeFromSuperview];      
UIView* audioView= audioviewcontroller.view;        
[theWindow addSubview:audioView];       
[self.navController pushViewController:audioviewcontroller animated:YES];       [audioviewcontroller release];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
```

I get no warning but a crash and the debugger console shows:

```
2011-10-26 10:01:59.344 subview[971:207] -[__NSCFTimer numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b44880
2011-10-26 10:01:59.346 subview[971:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b44880'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dcf5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f23313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dd10bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d40966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d40522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0047a6ff -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _updateNumSections] + 111
    6   UIKit                               0x0047a3b0 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 66
    7   UIKit                               0x00331d23 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] + 113
    8   UIKit                               0x0032d65c -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 105
    9   UIKit                               0x0033a708 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773
    10  UIKit                               0x00337844 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01d6fa5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01d71ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01d170b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01d18294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01d1846d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00db089b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d456e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0e1d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0d840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0d761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x017261c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x01726289 GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002cdc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  subview                             0x000023b4 main + 102
    25  subview                             0x00002345 start + 53
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the codes below if it works for you, this is how I declare my objects/variables in the tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Declare your object (views) at the top of the function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 AudioViewController *audioviewcontroller = [[AudioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AudioViewController" bundle:nil];
 DisplayViewController *displayviewcontroller = [[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
 LichtViewController *lichtviewcontroller = [[LichtViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LichtViewController" bundle:nil];
 ProjektorViewController *projektorviewcontroller = [[ProjektorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjektorViewController" bundle:nil];

 if (indexPath.row==0) {
    NSLog(@"Index 0");
    [self.navController pushViewController:audioviewcontroller animated:YES];
    [audioviewcontroller release];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
 }
 if (indexPath.row==1) {
    NSLog(@"Index 1");
    [self.navController pushViewController:displayviewcontroller animated:YES];
    [displayviewcontroller release];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
 }
 if (indexPath.row==2) {
    [self.navController pushViewController:lichtViewController animated:YES];
    [lichtviewcontroller release];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Index 2");
 }
 if (indexPath.row==3) {
    NSLog(@"Index 3");
    [self.navController pushViewController:projektorviewcontroller animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated:YES];
    [projektorviewcontroller release];

 }
}
```

Comment: I tested it, but the effect is the same. The cells react by lighting up and out, but they do nothing

Comment: Have you tried changing from self.navController to self.navigationController?

Comment: Many thanks that was my fault. The UiViewController has a property navigationController, but I created a navController by myself, which led to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The proxy for the navigation controller associated with the view controller is `self.navigationController`, have you checked that this is not nil when you push a view controller on it?

You can't create your navigation controller from the view controller (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070851/add-a-navigation-controller-to-a-uiviewcontroller) for an explanation), you can find a tutorial on how to use UINavigationControllers [here](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uinavigationcontroller-by-example.aspx).

Comment: I am going to check it now. Thank you

Comment: I deklare the navigationController in the headerfile.

Comment: what kind of value is necessary for the navigationController?

Answer (score 0):

according to your error console i think there is problem is number of section.if you give the full tableview code then i think problem will be found.